# WP nonce invalid

Tags: php, plugin-development, nonce

Have a quick script to search for untranslated pages, and then returning a translate link. (Polylang makes a new post for a translation, which is then linked to the original.)

All is working well, except the nonce:

```php
$url = admin_url('post-new.php?post_type=product&from_post=' . $ID . '&new_lang=' . $lang);

$nonce_url = wp_nonce_url($url);
```

Returns a beautifully formatted url, with an invalid nonce:

`https://yaddayadda.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=product&from_post=2851&new_lang=nl&_wpnonce=fb63ac7002`

The link in the admin panel reads exactly the same, but with a working nonce:

`https://yaddayadda.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=product&from_post=2851&new_lang=nl&_wpnonce=c17b1a3a2a`

I like to think Im alright with WP, but this is breaking my head.
Does anyone have any sort of idea why it is generating invalid links??

Full code:

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

$lang = $_POST['lang'];
if ($lang == 'nl') { $language = 'Dutch';}
elseif ($lang == 'pt') { $language = 'Portuguese';}
else { $language = 'Something is going awry, I dont know ' . $lang;}

echo '<h2>Missing ' . $language . ' translations</h2>';
// An array of all published WC_Product Objects
$products = wc_get_products( array( 'status' => 'publish', 'limit' => -1,'lang' => 'en', ) );

// Displaying the number of products in this array
echo '<p>Total number of products published: ' . sizeof( $products ) . '</p>';

// Loop through products and save some data using WC_Product and stuff in array
$tobearray = [];
$count = 0;
foreach ( $products as $product ){
    $ID = $product->get_id();
    $title = $product->get_title();

    if (!pll_get_post($ID, $lang)) {

                  $url = admin_url('post-new.php?post_type=product&from_post=' . $ID . '&new_lang=' . $lang);

                  $nonce_url = wp_nonce_url($url);
                      //wp_nonce_url( $url);  // Adding our nonce to the url with a unique id made from the expiry timestamp

        $addpostlink = '<a href="' . wp_nonce_url('/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=product&from_post=' . $ID . '&new_lang=' . $lang) . '" target="_blank"> click here</a>';


        $tobearray[] = ['ID' => $ID, 'Title' => $title, 'Link' => $addpostlink ];
        $count++;
        }
}
echo '<p>Number of Products that are missing their ' . $lang . ' translation: ' . $count . '</p>';
echo 'Posts that need a ' . $language . ' translation: ';

?>
<p>
    Click on the link in the table below to create a new translation.  After the link opens (its a bit slow, pls wait), just open the original English product to copy and paste the title and description so you can translate them.
</p>
<table border="1">
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Link</th></tr> 
<?php foreach($tobearray as $row) {
  echo('<tr>');
  echo('<td>');
  echo(implode('</td><td>', $row));
  echo('</td>');
  echo('</tr>');
} ?>
</table>
```

Comment: [Nonces are per-user](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.2.2/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L2126) (and possibly per-user-session). Does the script run as the same user that's trying to use the link?

Comment: Well, its a plugin so I assumed it was run by the user logged into the admin section.  I cant find anything in the codex about setting a user either...  Would you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you tell us more about this script and how it's triggered? It is possible for things to run without any user, e.g. if it's running on a cron job, it's not clear what the script is though, it could be a WP CLI command, a Cron job, a standalone PHP file, etc. Why are you generating a nonce btw? And how is it being checked? I noticed there's no action specified for your nonce URL

Comment: Full code added.  It is a plugin file, the first page of which the (admin) user picks a language, and a POST variable is passed indicating the language.  My little script then checks for products which require a translation and generates links to do so.

Comment: At first glance from code in /wp-admin/ that uses wp_nonce_url, you don't want the /wp-admin/ in the string that you pass to wp_nonce_url. i.e. `'/wp-admin/' . wp_nonce_url('post-new.php?...')` or `admin_url(wp_nonce_url('post-new.php?...'))`. ... except now I've found some examples with admin_url or self_admin_url inside the wp_nonce_url. Maybe that's not it. I'd suggest you add trace to the wp_nonce_url and see what your version and the admin version are passing.

Comment: jah sorry, that was me trying every suggestion I found on the internet.  The original code was admin_url(wp_nonce_url('etc  generates exactly the same invalid nonce.  Would you know of a way to figure out what user runs the code, if not the wp user?  or how I can pass the user to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what the problem was.  Polylang plugin verifies the nonces, so you need to pass it the 'new-post-translation' arg.

The solution is:
wp_nonce_url( $link, 'new-post-translation' );

it might help someone, but maybe no ;)